# Set DefaultValue to DateTime.Now() Equivalent

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

How do I set a default value to the current date and time?

```xml
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_MyCustomClaim" DefaultValue="DateTime.Now()">
</OutputClaims>
```

`ClaimType` for reference:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="extension_MyCustomClaim">
    <DisplayName>Some Date/Time</DisplayName>
    <DataType>date</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="myCustomClaim" />
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="myCustomClaim" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <AdminHelpText>Some date time</AdminHelpText>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

**Update**

> Unable to upload policy. Reason : Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORK_BUILDINGBLOCKS" of tenant "my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com".The OutputClaims mismatched in ClaimsTransformation with id "GetSystemDateTime" with TransformationMethod "GetCurrentDateTime".
>
> The following OutputClaims were declared in the Policy but were not expected by the TransformMethod: [Date]currentDateTime. The following OutputClaims were expected by the TransformMethod but were not declared in the Policy: [DateTime]currentDateTime.

Wonder if I need an updated `base.xml` file?  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a claims transformation of type **GetCurrentDateTime** and then invoke this as an output claim transformation from the technical profile:

```xml
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetNow" TransformationMethod="GetCurrentDateTime">
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_MyCustomClaim" TransformationClaimType="currentDateTime" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

Also, the `DataType` of the `ClaimType` has to be `dateTime`

```xml
<ClaimType Id="extension_MyCustomClaim">
    ...
    <DataType>dateTime</DataType>
    ...
</ClaimType>
```

Comment: Thanks  Chris but it is not working for me .  I'm getting an error on upload.  Please see my updated question, thanks!

Comment: The data type for the claim type must be changed from `date` to `dateTime`.

Comment: Oh, I’ll try that, thanks!  And submit a PR for the XSD that only has `date`!